# Where to learn about 'Electrical Sound'?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, acoustics, resource-recommendations, superconductivity

Here is a thought experiment.

Consider a thin superconducting circular loop of wire. Suppose there is a supercurrent flowing through the loop. Let $v$ be the tangential drift velocity of the electrons and $r$ the radius of the loop.

Now suppose you place an observer at the center of the loop and they begin to rotate with angular velocity $\frac{v}{r}$. Then from their perspective the electrons are static. Now suppose you somehow "pushed" a set of electrons in the wire a little ahead, that would creative effectively an electrical pressure that should appear to propagate around the loop like a sound wave (from the rotating observer's point of view), (and could potentially be quantized).

Where can I learn more about this type of "electrical sound"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need complicated setups with superconductors. To a surprisingly good approximation the conduction electrons in a metal behave as a nearly ideal gas. This is the [free electron gas model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model), or unexcitingly named [nearly free electron gas model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearly_free_electron_model).

This electron gas supports oscillations that are the equivalent of sound waves, and with these comes a quasiparticle analogous to the phonon called the [plasmon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmon).

When I was doing my PhD there was lots of interest in plasmons. I'm not sure how active an area it is these days - I get the impression that the more esoteric aspects of electronic structure have largely taken over - but a quick Google will find lots of related material.